# MVC 3 RAZOR - @model IEnumerable - how to get specific value

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, ienumerable

In my view I am using:

```
@model IEnumerable<UserManager.Models.vw_UserManager_Model>
```

because I am using webgrid and my model to create a grid on my page. I am also trying to get a specific value from my model here:

```
<input name="User logged in" type="checkbox"  onclick="filterGrid('@Url.Action("FilterGrid", "UserManager", new { filterVal = Model.Single(model => model.alfIntelligence) })')" id="chkboxGridFilter" />
```

I don't know how to get the value from object that uses IEnumerable. Does anyone know the correct method to call on Model?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try `FirstOrDefault()`

```
var someValue = Model.FirstOrDefault().alfIntelligence;
```

and then use this variable where you want to.

If you could provide me with more details on `vw_UserManager_Model` I think I can provide you with a better answer, but I think this should do it for you.

Comment: Thanks that worked. I want to pass a boolean value to my actionMethod and then use that in my DAL to modify my webgrid. I wouldn't of thought of using FirstOrDefault like that. Guess I learned something new.